# Как перенести проект с одного аккаунта github на другой?

Tags: yii2, git, github

Есть проект project на github c аккаунтом A и email адресом A@gmail.com.
Возникла необходимость переноса проекта на другой аккаунт github B с email адресом B@gmail.com. При этом проект с аккаунта A загружен на удаленный сервер, поэтому надо сделать так, чтобы при следующем обновлении проекта на этом удаленном сервере я просто набирала данные проекта с нового аккаунта github B с репозитария project. Пока что с грубого удаления папки с гитом и инициации другого гита в голову ничего не пришло.

Comment: [Вот](https://help.github.com/en/articles/transferring-a-repository), пожалуйста.

Comment: Я так делала, выдает ошибку

Comment: Мы должны сами догадаться, что Вы делали и какую ошибку получили?

Comment: Если поменять репозиторий прямым удалением старого гита и включением нового, то при обновлении проекта git pull c адресом нового гита, проект поломается? Или надо в настройках гита прописать другие данные?

Comment: В аккаунте А в натсройках написано Transfer ownership
This repository is being transferred to @...  Затем перехожу по ссылке на почту аккаунта B и при переходе на github на любой из аккаунтов ошибка Oops! That repository transfer has expired. Мне теперь абортировать старый трнасфер и по новой передать?

Comment: А может имя надо было проекту сначала дать в аккаунте B, а потом трансфер делать?

Comment: Нашла ошибку, надо было зайти в аккаунт B, а потом по ссылке с почты заходить

Comment: А если использовать fork?

Comment: Клонировать проект на локалку и запушить в новый репозиторий.